# How to merge columns from one file to another in R for many files?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, cbind

I have over 100 files e.g. File_1,,,,,,File_100 like the below:

```
Position    Likelihood  Alpha
11885.0000  8.457955e-02    2.089548e+02
21877.3906  2.160398e+01    1.509296e-05
31869.7812  1.268591e+01    2.130559e-05
```

And more 100 files e.g. File_1,,,,,File_100 like the below:

```
Position    Likelihood  Alpha   StartPos    EndPos
11885.0000  0.000000e+00    1.200000e+03    11885.0000  32345.0000
21877.3906  0.000000e+00    1.200961e-03    11885.0000  32345.0000
31869.7812  1.083378e-01    6.004804e-04    11885.0000  32345.0000
```

I am trying to combine the StartPos and EndPos from the other files to the above files where I will have five columns eventually. So, I did something like this:

```
a<-read.table("File_1", header = T)
b<-read.table("File_1", header = T)
c<-cbind(a,b[4:5])
write.table(c, file="File_1.txt")
```

My question is, how can I put this command in a loop where it goes over all the 100 files from Directory A and 100 files from Directory B and produces a new file? The two groups of 100 files are in different directories.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `File_1` in a and b in the same folder ?

Comment: Not actually. They are in different folders. But they can be put into the same folder.

Comment: Of course you must not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this but you must specify the folders in your system e.g. `"/Users/mohamed/File_"`

```
for(i in 1:100){
    a<-read.table(paste0("/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-3/Report_Chr_" , i), header = T)
    b<-read.table(paste0("/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-4/Report_Chr_" , i), header = T)
    c<-cbind(a,b[4:5])
    write.table(c, file=paste0("Report_Chr_" , i , ".txt"))
    
}
```

this must save the new files in your working directory.

Comment: Ah, sorry, a silly question. how can I specify the folders in that code?

Comment: See above if it help.

Comment: Actually, I ran into a problem. It says 
`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-3/Report_1': No such file or directory`

My files are names like `Report_Chr_1, Report_Chr_2, Report_Chr_3`.
I ran the code being on a new directory and then specify the path to the other two directories as you mentioned.

Comment: Ok , this first folder path `/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-3/` , if so what is the path of the second ?

Comment: `/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-4` is the second and `/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-5` is the destination folder path where I want to save the new files.

Comment: Try the above .

Comment: Still, the problem persists. Same error message. Being on the folder V-5 as a working directory, if I execute the command for a reduced number of files like this:

`for(i in 1:12){
  a<-read.table(paste0("/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-3/Report_Chr_" , i), header = T)
  
b<-read.table(paste0("/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-4/Report_Chr_" , i), header = T)
  
c<-cbind(a,b[4:5])
  
write.table(c, file=paste0("/Users/Documents/First_results/new_file/V-5/Report_Chr_" , i , ".txt"))
  
}`
I get the same error message.

Comment: Hi, it has finally worked. I needed to give the full name of the files. Thanks a lot for your help.